# How to correct normals along the Z axis

Tags: modeling, normals

Im creating grass for my scene and have watched a walk through which says Alt+N > Point to target > Z axis large value, which should point all the split normals straight up, but end up leaning.

I thought I would have to freeze transforms, but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: This should work, provided that the Z value is indeed quite large (e.g. 100000 m). Alternatively you could use ALT-L, enable align with A, then press M and control the normals with your mouse. This will however be less accurate as you will have to estimate the alignment. You could also set them through a Python script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the custom split normals to be perfectly aligned with the Z-axis in object space you can accomplish this with the following script:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
custom_normals = [(0., 0., 1.) for loop in obj.data.loops]
obj.data.normals_split_custom_set(custom_normals)
```

For alignment in world space you can use the following script instead:

```
import bpy
import mathutils

obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
custom_normals = [mathutils.Vector((0., 0., 1.)) @ obj.matrix_world for loop in obj.data.loops]
obj.data.normals_split_custom_set(custom_normals)
```

1. Switch to to the *Scripting* workspace.
2. Copy and paste one of the scripts to the text editor.
3. Switch to object mode in the 3D view and select the object for which the normals should be aligned with the Z-axis.
4. Run the script by pressing the play button in the text editor's header.

Comment: I think the reason why its leaning is because it's a plane, when I've tried it on a sphere or square it works. Also I tried the script and I'm getting an error not sure if I'm using it right.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. What error are you getting?

Comment: When I run it without the import bpy I get Python script failed, check the message in the system console. When I try the full text nothing happens also Im sorry this is the first time I've used a script.

Comment: If you execute the script as shown above and its throws no error, then you should see the changed normals when switching back to edit mode.

Comment: You're right but for what every reason my normals for the grass stay slanted and when i try it on other planes they are also the same. but the script does work, awesome. I think my only option is to manually fix it with enable align at point

Comment: Bear in mind that this script aligns normals to Object-Space Z, not World-Space Z ?

Comment: Yes, if the object is rotated (axis of object space does not match world space), then this will only align with the local Z-axis. Alignment with the global Z-axis can be achieved by adding `import mathutils` and using `custom_normals = [mathutils.Vector((0., 0., 1.)) @ obj.matrix_world for loop in obj.data.loops]` instead.