# How to clean up a model after rotating it from the pivot point in object mode?

Tags: modeling, normals

When I rotate my model from the pivot point and then try to align the split normal's to any of the axis, it keeps the rotation for the split normal's even after setting transforms to deltas.[image]

The Left is the one I'm rotating in object mode, but wanting the split normals to be like the right one.

This is for grass I'm creating, so I was trying to figure out what was going wrong, it seems whenever I rotate it in object mode it then wont align properly.

Comment: Normals will rotate with the vertices. I don't think there is an option to keep them from rotating. I've updated my script in the answer to your [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261056/how-to-correct-normals-along-the-z-axis) for aligning the normals with the Z-axis in world space, but you would have to run this every time you change the rotation.

Comment: You're amazing thank you so much for your help.